# Django 3.0.9 error message courses.File.file: (models.E006) The field 'file' clashes with the field 'file' from model 'courses.itembase'

Tags: django

I am teaching myself Django using the book Django 3 by example I have worked my way thru the book and have come up against an error message

error message courses.File.file: (models.E006) The field 'file' clashes with the field 'file' from model 'courses.itembase'.
and

courses.Image.file: (models.E006) The field 'file' clashes with the field 'file' from model 'courses.itembase'

I have used the documentation [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/) and am I correct in understanding that
"fields of the model. Each field is specified as a class attribute, and each attribute maps to a database column."
In my case the "class file" and "class image" are sharing the attribute "file" which is added as a database column. Looking at other solutions I have tried to rename the attribute and come up against a request to

1. Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
2. Quit, and let me add a default in models.py

Does this indicate that there are two columns in the database named "file" which I have to identify with a unique attribute. Looking at documentation I see I have used Models.Filefield correctly [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#model-field-types), could you guide me to documentation about how do you add a default for this error in models.py?

```
class ItemBase(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User,
                              related_name='%(class)s_related',
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

def render(self):
        return render_to_string(
            f'courses/content/{self._meta.model_name}.html',
            {'item': self})

class Meta:
    abstract = True

def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Text(ItemBase):
    content = models.TextField()

class File(ItemBase):
        file = models.FileField(upload_to='files')

class Image(ItemBase):
        file = models.FileField(upload_to='images')

class Video(ItemBase):
        url = models.URLField()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't set same related name in more that one model in django so what you have to do is you have to change your related name to something like this or it this doesn't work then you have to put that manually in the all classes with different related name

```
owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Thank you Kishan I have chaged the related names in the classes. It has worked perfectly!